# eway direct payment curl code not working

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway

I am trying to charge the customer using eway payment method. I am implementing the procedure through curl and here is the code to the function.

```
 public function testing_direct() {


    $url = 'https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/DirectPayment.json'; // PROD
    $postData = array(
        'Method' => 'TokenPayment',
        'TransactionType' => 'Recurring',
        'TokenCustomerID' => '918549937032',
        'TotalAmount' => '1995',
        'InvoiceNumber' => '123',
        'InvoiceDescription' => 'testing'
    );

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $api_authentication = base64_encode('####;****');

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json','Authorization:####'
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors
    if ($response === FALSE) {
        die(curl_error($ch));
    }


    $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    print_r($responseData);
    die;
}
```

This code doesnot print anything at all...Nothing in the error log either...any ideas that why it is not working??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be fix to get that script working, particularly around the authentication which is the most immediate cause of a problem.

There needs to be a check of the HTTP status of the request since `curl_exec` only returns FALSE if there is an error - e.g. a 404 (page not found) or 401 (unauthorized) is still treated as a successful request.

```php
// Check for errors
if ($response === FALSE) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}

$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($code != 200) {
    die('HTTP error: '.$code);
}
```

The actual authentication appears to suffer from 2 main issues: there is a semicolon instead of a colon between the username (API key) and password, and the `Basic` part of the authentication is missing:

```php
$api_authentication = base64_encode('####:****');

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Basic '.$api_authentication
),
```

This could be simplified by just using `CURLOPT_USERPWD`:

```php
CURLOPT_USERPWD => '####:****',
```

Apart from that, note that the `$postData` array needs some extra nesting: `TokenCustomerID` should be a child of `Customer` and `TotalAmount` and the `Invoice` fields should be children of `Payment`:

```php
$postData = array(
    'Method' => 'TokenPayment',
    'TransactionType' => 'Recurring',
    'Customer' => array(        
      'TokenCustomerID' => '911058757297',
    ),
    'Payment' => array(
        'TotalAmount' => '1900',
        'InvoiceNumber' => '123',
        'InvoiceDescription' => 'testing',
     ),
);
```

Check out the example [in the documentation](http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/eway/api/eway-rapid-31-api/docs/reference/direct-connection) for a complete example request.

Good luck!